# Using datetime as key in list in R

Tags: r

Running this example trying to create a list with a datetime as a key ends up allocating a list of 11.2 Gb.

How should I do this better?

```
now <- now()
foo <- list()
foo[[now]] <- "test"
```

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 11.2 Gb

Comment: That is understandable `length(foo)#
[1] 1508229580`. now() returns a date-time object.  I think `foo` would be starting from the `origin` date..   Instead initiate the `list` with particular length i..e `foo <- vector('list', 10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply try converting now to Character vector before using it in a list.

```
now <- now()
foo <- list()
now <- as.character(now)
foo[[now]] <- "test"
```